# Synergy: avoid single machine loop when client is not connected

Tags: synergy

In order to loop between my screens I have the following section in my `synergy.sgc` file:

```
section: links
    Pedro-Acer:
        right = pedro-lubuntu
        left = pedro-lubuntu
    pedro-lubuntu:
        left = Pedro-Acer
        right = Pedro-Acer
end
```

With those settings when the client disconnects, the server screen wraps around itself as seen in the image below. I don't want this behavior.

The only reason I set the config file to loop between my screens is because I want to have a single key to switch between them:

```
keystroke(alt+`) = switchInDirection(right)
```

If there is way to have a single key for switching in both directions without having looping screens then that would also solve my problem.

[image]